# Cannot access LocalDB using SSMS when IIS is running

Tags: sql-server

I have a web site app running on IIS 7.5 that access a LocalDb, all installed on same server.

Using SSMS, I can see the app db folder in the object explorer but when I try to expand it, I get an error saying that the database is not accessible. If I stop the web site in IIS then I can access it.

Is there a way that I can work on the database in SSMS simultaneously while the clients are accessing the web app ?

I log in the SSMS as administrator using Windows authentication. The web app log in as "IIS AppPool\AutoParkDemo" using the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

```
      <connectionStrings>
   <clear />
   <add name="AutoPark" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=AutoParkDemo;AttachDbFilename=C:\AutoPark\Demo\Data\AutoParkDemo.mdf;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I found the answer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found out is that each application that access LocalDB simultaneously, must have its own shared instance. There is a good tutorial about it on MS site, but the problem is that if there is no activity the shared instance stops and, although I read on Microsoft website that it will restart automatically, it didn't happen to me. After struggling for couple weeks, I decided to use the suggestion from other post on this site: When deploying to a web site with IIS, use SQLExpress instead. It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

IIS server needs to have exclusive access to local db file, that is the main reason you can't access to database using SSMS.

In theory you could have read-only access to local db while IIS is running on background. I use often Visual Studio and IIS, and I can access local db while web server is running.

I believe SSMS needs write access to works with local db. This could be the reason why VS can read and SSMS not.